# NodeJS TypeError: Model is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I have an Angular5 app that is making requests to my NodeJS Api, specifically I'm trying to do a `put` request. The first time it works fine, but on the second time I call it, it says that my Model is not a constructor. I'm using Mongoose in NodeJS.

Here is the piece of code in NodeJS:

```
var Aviamentos = require('./../models/Aviamentos');
router.put('/:receitaId/prescricoes/:prescricaoId/aviar', function (req, res) {
    let aviamento = new Aviamentos({ // <-- It fails on this line the second time
        Farmaceutico: req.body.Farmaceutico,
        Data: new Date(),
        Quantidade: req.body.Quantidade,
    });
    ...
```

Here is my Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var aviamentoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Farmaceutico: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
    },
    Data: Date,
    Quantidade: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model( 'Aviamentos', aviamentoSchema);
```

The first time I execute the request on the AngularJS side, it works fine, but the second time I get this erro: `TypeError: Aviamentos is not a constructor`

Here is my function in Angular5:

```
aviarPrescricao(idReceita: string, idPrescricao: string, Quantidade: number){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let body = {
        Quantidade: Quantidade,
        Farmaceutico: '5a08540a243ad41cf0659376'
    };
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL + '/' + idReceita + '/prescricoes/' + idPrescricao + '/aviar', JSON.stringify(body), { headers: headers })
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model js you have already declared Schema:

So change:

```
var aviamentoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    //code
});
```

to

```
var aviamentoSchema = new Schema({
    //code
});
```